# AngularJS: POST parameters in array notation

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

My angular.js app posts the following JSON to my backend API:

```
{"pickupAddress":
                {"state":"d","country":"d","city":"d","zipCode":"d","street":"d"},
 ...}`
```

Instead of that my backend API required to receive not `pickupAddress.state`, but `pickupAddress[state]`.

I tried to change the `ng-model` in my view (to `myObject.pickupAddress['country']`) but this produces some strange errors.

I want something which results in this (using raw html):

`<input type="text" name="pickupAddress[state]" />`

Comment: It's unclear what you mean... do you want to send different JSON to backend API or is the problem something else?

Comment: I want Angular to use array notation. With raw HTML this would be like `<input type="text" name="pickupAddress[state]" />`

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: If there's only a solution with jQuery, I'll accept that one. In perfect case there is an easy solution without jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is not needed, there will be a simple solution with angular js

Comment: @CallumLinington Probably, feel free to post, it's interesting. I can give a jQuery solution off the top of my head. There is another way which involves `transformRequest` function I guess.

Comment: @CallumLinington: Can you provide an example/clarify your statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Angular serializes POST data if you provide an object source is in fact uses not notation your service expects. If instead you use jQuery $.param method to serialize object into param-string and post this string, it should work:

```
var data = $.param({
    "pickupAddress": {
        "state": "d",
        "country": "d",
        "city": "d",
        "zipCode": "d",
        "street": "d"
    }
});

$http.post('test', data, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

Above will post data as

```
pickupAddress[state]:d
pickupAddress[country]:d
pickupAddress[city]:d
pickupAddress[zipCode]:d
pickupAddress[street]:d
```

Check this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6039) in Angular issue page.

Comment: Thanks. Especially the link in the discussion page pointing to http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/ was very helpful. This was the solution I'm using.